# java script to get xml from url

Tags: javascript

I am writing a js to get a xml from a url but i am not getting any response.Anything I am doing wrong?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(response)
                {
                    alert(response);
                }
        });


    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4bh0qpb1/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First script syntax error (") that you have fixed, although you can't access following url `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml` using ajax due to CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) Policy.

**Reason**
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: Thanks girish how to enable CORS

Comment: you can't enable CORS on other domain... it's defined in repose header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: But if i do the same request using java  like jersey client /webservice client I get a response how is it possible?

Comment: use PHP CURL concept.... since you don't have control over W3schools.

I know you are looking a javascript solution but it is better to use any server side language like PHP,JAVA to get XML data.

Comment: @chiru you should use same domain url and get `api` response using CURL on server script.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to end url parameter with double quote "